# Nvidia Theano docker image not available

Tags: python, docker, theano, nvidia, jupyter-notebook

Trying to run docker command :

```
nvidia-docker run -d -p 8888:8888  -e PASSWORD="123abcChangeThis" theano_secure start-notebook.sh
# Then open your browser at http://HOST:8888
```

taken from https://github.com/nouiz/Theano-Docker

returns error :

```
Error: image library/theano_secure:latest not found
```

Appears the theano_secure image is not currently available ?

Searching for theano_secure :

```
$ nvidia-docker search theano_secure:latest
NAME      DESCRIPTION   STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
```

The return of this command is empty so image is not available ? 
If so is there an alternative Theano docker image from nvidia ?

Update :

building from source :

```
docker build -t theano_secure -f  Dockerfile.0.8.X.jupyter.cuda.secure .
```

returns :

```
Err http://developer.download.nvidia.com  Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to developer.download.nvidia.com:http: [IP: 184.24.98.231 80]
```

and :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
```

Manually checking URL's : http://developer.download.nvidia.com & http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease are both not available. Should I build with alternative docker file ?

Update 2 :

I think this error is occurring as  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease does not exist. However http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release does exist.

Can docker be modified to use http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release instead of http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease ?

OS version :

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Update 3 :

"you are supposed to docker build first", before nvidia-docker run" I did try

```
docker build -t theano_secure -f  Dockerfile.0.8.X.jupyter.cuda.secure .
```

which returns :

```
Err http://developer.download.nvidia.com  Release.gpg Unable to connect to developer.download.nvidia.com:http: [IP: 184.24.98.231 80]
```

I can pull image `docker pull kaixhin/theano` but this does not run via Jupyter notebook in same way as `nvidia-docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu` documented at https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/ . There does not appear to be a docker Jupyter Theano container available.

How to expose the docker instance kaixhin/theano via Jupyter notebook ?

I tried : `nvidia-docker run -d -p 8893:8893 -v --name theano2 kaixhin/theano start-notebook.sh` but receive error :

```
    docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: 
starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"start-notebook.sh\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n".
```

Modification of `kaixhin/theano` docker container in order expose it via Jupyter notebook ?

Comment: You're supposed to build the `theano_secure` image yourself, from the README: `docker build -t theano_secure -f  Dockerfile.0.8.X.jupyter.cuda.secure .`

Comment: @gjtempleton please see update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Error: image library/theano_secure:latest not found
```

Because `theano_secure` doesn't like `ubuntu`,`centos`, it is not official repository on docker hub, so you need to build it by yourself.

```
Err http://developer.download.nvidia.com  Release.gpg Unable to connect to developer.download.nvidia.com:http: [IP: 184.24.98.231 80]
```

Please check your internet connection first, `telnet 184.24.98.231 80`.

Maybe you are in a limited network place, try behind a proxy to do this again. You may want take a look about how to [build image behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41490826/3378901).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of the [`nouiz/Theano-Docker README`](https://github.com/nouiz/Theano-Docker), you are supposed to `docker build` first, before `nvidia-docker run`.

But since the build is tricky, I would try instead [`docker pull kaixhin/theano`](https://hub.docker.com/r/kaixhin/theano/)  (from [`kaixhin/cuda-theano/`](https://hub.docker.com/r/kaixhin/cuda-theano/)), much more recent (3 days ago), which is based on [`theano Dockerfile`](https://github.com/Kaixhin/dockerfiles/blob/master/theano/Dockerfile).

That image does rely on [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html)and needs to be run on an Ubuntu host OS with NVIDIA Docker installed. The driver requirements can be found on the [NVIDIA Docker wiki](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/CUDA#requirements).